# How to understand this question 'what did you shop for?'

Tags: questions

I clearly understand the meaning of 'what did you shop?' But I don't understand this 'for' at the end.

Comment: Compare:    Who did you write *to*?    What building did you live *in*?   What pony did you sit *on*?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. Context is very important to meaning—there are several different meanings of *shop*, for example—so we can only provide a definitive answer if you tell us the circumstances where you have encountered this sentence—who is saying it and what are the surrounding sentences? Please [edit] your post to include this information. I further encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for guidance on writing strong, answerable questions.

Answer (score 2):

There is a subtle difference between the verb "shop" by itself, and the phrasal verb "shop for".  In the context of ordinary commerce: By itself, "shop" simply implies the activity of going out and (potentially) buying things *from shops*.  "Shop for" instead implies the activity of buying some *specific* item from the shops.

Example:

> Yesterday we went **shopping** (= we had no specific purchase in mind)
>
> Yesterday we went **shopping for** [warm winter coats for the kids]

You cannot ask "What did you shop?" if you want to know the intended purchase.  Instead you must ask "what did you shop *for*?"  However you may ask more general questions such as:

> **When** did you shop?
>
> **Where** did you shop?
>
> **Who** did you shop with?

or other questions that may not directly relate to the intended items.

Side Note: "Shop" has other, colloquial, and relatively uncommon definitions.  For these, "What did you shop?" might be fine.

Comment: I would take *What did you shop?* to mean *What did you try to* ***sell***? As in, *I shopped my idea to various clients.*

Comment: @JasonBassford  That's a different definition of "shop".  It could also be *'shop*, as in *Photoshop*, plus any other colloquialisms.

Comment: Quite right. There is nothing at all in the sentence *Why did you shop?*  that specifies a particular meaning. Aside from the fact that without a preposition it's the selling meaning that I interpret it as. If *for* is added, then I'd think of buying. So, your first two sentences are not really accurate. Barring context, there's more than just a subtle difference.

Comment: @JasonBassford  I wrote *"You cannot ask "What did you shop?" **if you want to know the intended purchase***.  In other words, in this particular context, it doesn't work.  For a different, colloquial definition of "shop", sure, it might, but that seems outside the scope of the question.

Comment: The question says, literally, "I clearly understand the meaning of 'what did you shop?'" Well, I don't because *shop* has multiple meanings. Nowhere does it mention purchasing anything. You added that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

*Shop* is an intransitive verb: it does not take an object. The things we intend to purchase are expressed with a preposition phrase headed by *for*:

> We shopped ***for*** clothes at Marks & Spencer.

Consequently, when you ask your respondent to name the thing or things they intended to purchase, the interrogative (*what*) must be cast as the object of *for*. When the interrogtative is fronted it may carry the preposition with it ('pied-piping') —

> ***For*** what did you shop?

—or the preposition may be left in place ('stranded'):

> *What* did you shop ***for***?

Pied-piping is preferred in formal registers, stranding in informal registers.

Answer (score 0):

Without any other context, **shop** in your first sentence can have an ambiguous meaning.

> What did you shop?

The use of a preposition clarifies the intended sense of the word.

> What did you shop **for** (this Christmas)?

This is asking what you purchased. It's the more common of possible meanings, but it's not the only one.

> What did you shop **around** (to the executives)?

Here, it's asking what you were trying to *sell*. The expression *shopping something around* is often used in the sense of trying to market an idea or product.

> What did you shop **out** (of the picture)?

Here, it's being used in the colloquial sense of Photoshop, the popular graphic-editing application. It might be styled as *Shop* or *'shop*, but often isn't. This sentence is asking what element was removed from a picture.

---

In each case, the use of a preposition makes the intended meaning of **shop** clear, distinguishing it from other interpretations.

As I mentioned, context can also make it clear, and often context means you don't have to use a preposition. But without context, a preposition will aid in the prevention of any misinterpretation.